# Recursion on console.log(this) in object specific method toString

Tags: javascript, object

So, I'm creating an object with toString method and then call it:

```js
const object = {
    toString() {
        console.log(this);
    },
};

object.toString();
```

And after I've invoked the method, console recursively logs object then, like this:

```
script.ts:207 {toString: ƒ}
script.ts:207 {toString: ƒ}
script.ts:207 {toString: ƒ}
```

It happens only with toString method and when I log object itself.

What's happening here, why it's recursive? Somebody help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `toString` method is calling `console.log` which *may* need (for its own displaying purposes) to stringify the argument you pass to it. But since that argument is `this`, it leads to a recursive call of `toString` (implicitly), and again, and again...

The purpose of `toString` is to *return* the string representation of your object, not to *print* it. If you really, really think it necessary (for debugging?) to use `console.log` inside the `toString` method, then don't pass `this` to `console.log`, but pass something that is already a string.

```js
const object = {
    toString() {
        return "my object";
    },
};

console.log(object.toString()); // my object
```